# Flag More Than One Space in SQL

Tags: sql, fme-form

I am working on an XP machine with FME'13 and I have a *Address* field and I have to find the spaces(middle spaces and not the leading and trailing ) in each and every row.

**St._Petters_Road** is the valid space(it need not be flagged); but
**St.__Petters_Road** is invalid (as it has two consecutive whitespaces).

It is assumed that the words are correct. But there should not be two two consecutive spaces.

and I need to flag the invalid attributes in a new column as 0 and 1
Can we do that with transformers or in SQL?

Answer (score 2):

One option is use Tester with LIKE (operator) and  `'%__%'` (right value) (passed)--> to AttributeCreator (add column changed, set value to 1) Or Tester with RegExp, but i dont know regexp that well that i can say correct value for it. You can use SQL too , it will be faster if you import data from sql db. (WHERE field LIKE `'%__%'`)

If you want remove those `__` from value field, then you can use StringReplacer with 
"Text to find" `__` and Replace `"_"`, or use regexp which may be able to handle all cases with too many `_`. If you don't want have that changed field you can just use StringReplacer.

Also if you meant `_` to be just space then use `%  %` in LIKE operator (see two spaces ) :) Same can be used in StringReplacer

edit: __ may not be correctly in answer because site seems to convert % and _ to bolded text

Comment: +1 for suggesting regexp.  It could capture all instances of too many spaces instead of using multiple testers.

Comment: @Fetzer , my regexp is weak. Can you show example for replace two or more characters with only one

Comment: Use the StringReplacer transformer, set it to use regular expressions.  Put in "\s{2,}" (without the quotes) to search for and your replacement text will be a single space.  That will search for 2 or more whitespace characters.  Safe software recommends [Rubular.com](http://rubular.com/) to test regular expressions.  You build your expression at the top and put your test string below.  It's how I've taught myself regular expressions.